# Salesforce OpenID Connect - /.well-known/openid-configuration blocked by CORS

Tags: cors, salesforce, openid-connect

I am trying to read the /.well-known/openid-configuration from an ***Salesforce OpenID Connect*** implementation.

I can see the file in browser but the file cannot be loaded by script:

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxx.force.com/.well-known/openid-configuration' from origin 'https://pds-dev' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

Is there a way to enable CORS for this static file in Salesforce?

Thank you,
Radu

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce [does not allow CORS on unauthenticated resources](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=extend_code_cors.htm&type=5).

As a workaround, the least intrusive approach is a CORS [proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe). A simple implementation of a CORS proxy in the Salesforce world would be a custom Apex REST service with API authorization via the usual Salesforce oAuth semantics. The service would grab OIDC config and retransmit it in HTTP response. You can then [whitelist your origin in SF](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=extend_code_cors.htm&type=5) and get past the CORS check.

UPDATE: As of Winter '21 release (live in Sept-Oct '20), [CORS is allowed](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_security_oauth_cors.htm) on the following resources without any additional config steps:

```
/.well-known/openid-configuration
/.well-known/auth-configuration
/services/oauth2/id/keys
```

Comment: This looks like a workaround, might use it as fallback
I am somehow surprised that the Salesforce OpenID Connect is ignoring javascript clients for the SSO implementation in 2019.

Comment: Yup, unfortunately that's the current state of the art. If you create an enhancement Idea on [IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch), you'll have our upvote.